# Converting bulky shapefiles (54 MB) to GeoJSON

Tags: shapefile, geojson, convert, geotools

I am trying to convert my shapefile to GeoJSON using the below code snippet:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
String geoJson = null;
FeatureJSON fjson = new FeatureJSON();
fjson.writeFeatureCollection(col, writer);
```

This works fine for small shapefiles but when I try to convert a file that is of 54 MB the system gets hung.

What should I do differently? Or is there another approach to convert big shapefiles to GeoJSON?

Comment: Forgot to mention I am using Geotools libraries to implement this.

Comment: If you think a 54Mb shapefile is bulky, the GeoJSON equivalent is going to blow your socks off -- 20:1 expansion would not be unreasonable for such a conversion. Maybe you should be looking to generalize the dataset...

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide clarifications.

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

As with all of this sort of task in [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) you need to make use of [`FeatureCollection`s](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main/collection.html) and [`DataStores`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/datastore.html) to make life easy.

```
File inFile = new File("/home/ian/Data/states/states.shp");
File outFile = new File("/home/ian/Data/states/states.geojson");
outFile.createNewFile();
// Read
DataStore inputDataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(
        Collections.singletonMap("url", URLs.fileToUrl(inFile)));

String inputTypeName = inputDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
SimpleFeatureType inputType = inputDataStore.getSchema(inputTypeName);

FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature>
        source = inputDataStore.getFeatureSource(inputTypeName);

FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature>
        inputFeatureCollection = source.getFeatures();

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(GeoJSONDataStoreFactory.URLP.key, URLs.fileToUrl(outFile));
// Write
DataStore newDataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);

newDataStore.createSchema(inputType);
String typeName = newDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

SimpleFeatureStore featureStore =
        (SimpleFeatureStore) newDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

featureStore.addFeatures(inputFeatureCollection);
newDataStore.dispose();
inputDataStore.dispose();
```

Comment: Ian Turton.. Thanks man .. it reduces the processing time  now.